# Running Jasmine test cases

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write Jasmine test cases for our Javascript code but is geting stuck in between (I am a newbie to Jasmine). The scenario is something like this

```
var someVariable = true,

var getSomeVariable = function() {
    return someVariable;
}

var someFunction = function(dom) {
    if (!getSomeVariable()) {
        dom.enable();
        ...
    } else {
        dom.disable();
    }
}
```

So all we need is to write Jasmine test cases for someFunction() to test for dom.enable() and dom.disable() depending on the value that would be returned from the function getSomeVariable(), but I am not getting how to proceed with this. Can someone please advise or give the link of some good tutorials on Jasmine?

Regards,
Anirban.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout their documentation, everything is explained in it: http://jasmine.github.io/

In order to know which function will get run or not, you will need to spyOn them so in your test cases you can check if they have been called:

.toHaveBeenCalledWith()
.not.toHaveBeenCalled()